# How can I hide "Sent from my iPhone" in the emails I receive?

Tags: gmail

When I receive an email, I'm annoyed to see "Sent from my iPhone" or other phone mentions. Is there any way to hide it in Gmail (web interface)?

Comment: it's a signature. You can't hide signatures. Gmail will fold signatures, provided it's under a `--` mark.

Comment: Maybe some browser extensions could hide pre-defined sentences?

Answer (score 1):

To remove it from gmail I would try to write or find a javascript using browser extension:

- GreaseMonkey for firefox
- TamperMonkey for chrome
- I don't know for IE sorry

You have to know people do not remove this mentions for one of the following reason:

- They don't know how to remove it
- They are proud to have an iphone
- They want people to know they are not on a computer so the message can be short and with typo, so it's a kind of excuse.

I would update mine with sth like

'sorry this message has been written from a phone'

Answer (score -1):

I do not see this problem occurring when I use gmail (web interface) on my iphone through the Google search app, Chrome app, or Safari.

When Gmail is setup on your stock iPhone mail app then...
Using iPhone, you can go into SETTINGS, then MAIL.CONTACTS.CALENDARS, scroll down to SIGNATURE, and edit the setting appropriately.

Source: iPhone user

Comment: _Is there any way to hide it in Gmail (web interface)?_